# print binarySearchTree recursicely to file

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

i'm trying to write a bst to a file in c++, the tree will be printed inOrder.
note: when i print to screen i see that it is really inOrder with all the nodes.

```
ofstream file;
file.open(output);
if (bs != NULL)
{
    if (bs->getLeft())
        printTreeToFile(bs->getLeft(), output);

    file << bs->getData();

    if (bs->getRight())
        printTreeToFile(bs->getRight(), output);
}
```

i need to solve it as fast as possible so thank you all!!

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: how to write it correct:(
it doesnt write it to the file ..only one element from the middle

Comment: Can you please send us your teacher assignment?

Comment: i need to add elements to binary search tree and in this method i need to write to file the tree in-order,when the program is done the file contains only one element from the tree but doesn't write all the elements. i believe the way i wrote it is wrong

Comment: It seems like you are trying to open the output file (without checking if it is ok) inside your recursive function, while you should do it only once and before the first call of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're opening the file in every recursive call, which won't work.

It's more useful to write a function that takes an `std::ostream&` than a file name:

```
void printTree(Tree* bs, std::ostream& os)
{
    if (bs != NULL)
    {
        printTree(bs->getLeft(), os);
        os << bs->getData();
        printTree(bs->getRight(), os);
    }
}

// ...
// Example use:
// Print to standard out
printTree(tree, cout);

// Print to a file
ofstream file(filename);
printTree(tree, file);
```